# Why should I use a UI Pattern Framework for WPF, SL and WP7?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light, caliburn.micro

I've been learning SL over the past month and have now shifted my focus toward UI Pattern Frameworks such as Caliburn.Micro and MVVM-Light.

I recently attended a session at a conference on Using the MVVM Pattern with WPF and SL.  The presenter demonstrated using the pattern plain, without any UI Frameworks -- very simple and straight forward.  In the presentation he recommended that we create a base VM to be able to use some common functionality (wasn't able to get more specifics due to time -- please feel free to clarify).  Is this *a reason* why I would want to use a UI Pattern Framework?

My understanding is that UI Pattern Frameworks help implement patterns like MVVM by convention, thus allowing devs to not have to worry about that.  Why else would I use a UI Pattern Framework?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rich,

For business app - your VM most likely going to need at least 2 interfaces:

`INotifyPropertyChanged` and `INotifyDataErrorInfo`

Like Kieren said - implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` is very easy, couple lines of code. `INotifyDataErrorInfo` is little more but not bad.

MVVM Light is so "light" I'm not even sure what's is the point :) To me - someone who understands what MVVM about doesn't need this. You can look at it's source code to see what it does because most likely you will need to expand on that base class.

Caliburn, OTOH, is a convention-based framework which allows you bind without specifying "Bindings" and other magic like this. You need to decide if you really need it...

If you are working on something **heavy**, like LOB application with lot's of forms and stuff - I strongly suggest looking into PRISM. It's not an MVVM framework, it's framework to build complex composite UI. Learning curve will be steep, not like MVVMLight :) But it will cover most bases in your business application.

Comment: Just a warning: the prism manual is hundreds of pages, it is HUGE.  If you learn the framework, it will take others a similarly huge amount of time to become equipped to deal with it if you have to pass it on.

Comment: Not necessary agree about "others" part. Yes, it was hard for me to embrace it. But after it's in use - others just need to understand what the parts is and just add views similarly. Use events similarly, etc. Much easier. OTOH, it will save ton's of time writing something like this yourself.

Comment: @Rich - PRISM has very little to do with MVVM. MVVM is a pattern. PRIMS is a framework. MVVMLight has nothing to do with composite UI. PRIMS helps you build composite UI with DI/IoC, modules, regions, event aggregation and navigation. Non of that related to MVVM. PRISM have INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and it has commanding. But it's not about MVVM. All of the PRISM pieces ala cart. You use what you need.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use a UI Pattern Framework is if it provides the functionality you need or want.

If you only need to use `INotifyPropertyChanged` and maybe a quick `RelayCommand`, write them yourself (since it's ~5 lines of code, a couple of classes, ~30 lines in all).

If you need more, use one of the pre-built frameworks.

Comment: I've been using an MVP framework for webforms which had convention based binding of the presenter. Caliburn.Micro has this functionality as well; helps minimize the plumbing, I think.  My understanding is that it enables development of composite UI too, which is add'l functionality I want.  Can I implement composite UI patterns with vanilla mvvm, without having to write a lot a of code?